# Sequence of topics for studying quantum theory (Research strategy)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, soft-question, education

I am trying to learn about the higher level basics of physics. I want to cover up all that is included in particle physics/quantum physics. Now being in high school, I only know partially about Newtonian physics. So what order of topics should be followed by an undergraduate to get an overall idea of the theories and interesting concept of quantum theory for pleasure as well as knowledge?

Comment: [Should I begin to study quantum mechanics or wait until I have a stronger base on easier topics?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9935/)

Comment: Being in high school you do not even know Newtonian mechanics. You think you know Newtonian mechanics, but what you know barely scratches the surface. At the very least you have to be able to understand ALL of the material in a book like Landau, Lifshitz "Volume I: A Course of Theoretical Physics"). After that you will be able to misunderstand all of quantum mechanics while studying it in university. About ten years later it will dawn on you why you misunderstood all of it and THEN you will begin learning it for real.

Comment: First you need Lagrangian mechanics. Then Hamiltonian mechanics. THEN you can start on nonrelativistic quantum mechanics. (By the way, modern quantum mechanics has been around for 80ish years and basically encompasses "all of modern physics".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the question is off topic, its a rare opportunity for a young person to connect with more senior physicists, so I'll share my thoughts:

There is a  vast, beautiful mathematical world waiting for you to discover - you haven't even seen a deep treatment of mechanics yet.  It takes a lot of work and a lot of dedication, to grasp, but we're all here because we think its worth it.  In short, this is what the typical (core) roadmap looks like.  While not strict, the order is kind of important here: you can't do a ton of complex analysis without calculus, and the ideas of quantum mechanics grew out of classical mechanics.

**Mathematics is the language of physics**.  A list of tools used by physicists:

- buckets full of algebra
- calculus (multi variable and vector fields)
- partial differential equations
- linear algebra (some group theory sprinkled in)
- complex analysis, (Fourier) transform analysis
- statistical analysis
- more advanced topics include group theory, topology, tensor theory, etc

The undergraduate **canon of physics almost always includes these topics**:

- Classical mechanics (a more advanced treatment than what you've seen)
- Quantum Mechanics
- Electricity and magnetism
- Thermal/Statistical physics
- More advanced include field theory, general relativity. Maybe less canonical but very common are circuits, optics, plasma physics, superconductivity, etc.

There is no reason not to study on your own.  Wikipedia is maybe the best first-pass resource available, but *you won't really learn anything until you start solving problems*.  If you get impossibly stuck, do something else and come back to it when you know more than you used to.  Finding someone to talk to about the same stuff will be tremendously helpful as well.  Hope this helps.